# to_timestamp encounter the fractional seconds must be between 0 and 999999999

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g, oracle11g

enter code herethis is the code

```
select to_timestamp('03-APR-13 01.15.31.6754542 PM','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS.FF4 AM') from dual;
```

i originally intended to  accurate millisecond  to 4 digits,but the error display.and i find if the digits of .ff is equal or greater than 7 which is the digits of 6754542,
for example:

```
select to_timestamp('03-APR-13 01.15.31.6754542  PM','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS.FF8 AM') from dual;
select to_timestamp('03-APR-13 01.15.31.6754542  PM','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS.FF9 AM') from dual;
```

and so on. they always disply 03-APR-13 01.15.31.675454200 PM,9 digits...
how can i   accurate millisecond  to 4 digits,or forever not?
please help me,thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  TO_CHAR(
    TO_TIMESTAMP('03-APR-13 01.15.31.6754542  PM',
               'DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS.FF AM'),
  'DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS.FF4 AM')
FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: yes,i found the fmt parameter of to_timestamp can only be .FF without any of digits,while to_char can be specified by digits such as your code